# Organisation class in salesforce

Tags: soql

When I wrote below query,

`SELECT Name,Address FROM Organization`

it shows that organization doesn't exist. When I referred the manual, it shows

> Customer Portal users can't access this object.

What does this mean?Cant I write a normal query on organization as I write on Lead or Account

Comment: What is your profile? i mean System admin or customer portal user?

Answer (score 0):

Check your User License/Profile/Role, according the docs - Customer Portal users can't access this object - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm